# Wait for a process to finish

Tags: bash, scripting, process, wait

Is there any builtin feature in Bash to wait for a process to finish?

The `wait` command only allows one to wait for child processes to finish.
I would like to know if there is any way to wait for any process to finish before proceeding in any script.

A mechanical way to do this is as follows but I would like to know if there is any builtin feature in Bash.

```
while ps -p `cat $PID_FILE` > /dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Let me give _two cautions_: 1. As [pointed out below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407912/780703) by [mp3foley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/231760/mp3foley), "kill -0" does not always work for POSIX. 2. Probably you also want to make sure that the process is not a zombie, which is virtually a terminated process. **See** [mp3foley's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407912/780703) and [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11719943/780703) for the details.

Comment: _Another caution_ ([originally pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058047/wait-for-any-process-to-finish/11719943#comment40829493_1127675) by [ks1322](http://stackoverflow.com/users/72178/ks1322) below): Using PID other than a child process is not robust. If you want a secure way, use e.g. IPC.

Answer (score 276):

#### To wait for any process to finish

Linux (doesn't work on Alpine, where ash doesn't support `tail --pid`):

```
tail --pid=$pid -f /dev/null
```

Darwin (requires that `$pid` has open files):

```
lsof -p $pid +r 1 &>/dev/null
```

#### With timeout (seconds)

Linux:

```
timeout $timeout tail --pid=$pid -f /dev/null
```

Darwin (requires that `$pid` has open files):

```
lsof -p $pid +r 1m%s -t | grep -qm1 $(date -v+${timeout}S +%s 2>/dev/null || echo INF)
```

Comment: Who would have known that `tail` would do this.

Comment: The linux solution appears to work for Cygwin and Solaris as well, based on a brief test with `sleep` (although the `pwait` solution below for Solaris is easier)

Comment: `tail` works under the hood by polling with `kill(pid, SIG_0)` to a process (discovered using `strace`).

Comment: Note that lsof uses polling, that `+r 1` is the timeout, I am personally looking for a solution for MacOS that does not use polling.

Comment: This trick **fails** for zombies. It's ok for processes you can't kill; `tail` has the line `kill (pid, 0) != 0 && errno != EPERM`.

Comment: @AlexanderMills, if you can tolerate your macOS system not going to sleep as the command executes, `caffeinate -w $pid` will do the trick.

Comment: Also bear in mind that for docker implementations like busybox, --pid has not been implemented in tail.

Comment: `tail --pid` is likely a GNU-ism.

Comment: my current version of macOS 10.14.6 (Mojave) supports
```tail --pid=$pid -f /dev/null```

Comment: Can we wait for multiple `pid`s somehow?

Comment: `tail --pid=$pid1 --pid=$pid2 -f /dev/null`

Answer (score 95):

There's no builtin.  Use `kill -0` in a loop for a workable solution:

```
anywait(){

    for pid in "$@"; do
        while kill -0 "$pid"; do
            sleep 0.5
        done
    done
}
```

Or as a simpler oneliner for easy one time usage:

```
while kill -0 PIDS 2> /dev/null; do sleep 1; done;
```

As noted by several commentators, if you want to wait for processes that you do not have the privilege to send signals to, you have find some other way to detect if the process is running to replace the `kill -0 $pid` call.  On Linux, `test -d "/proc/$pid"` works, on other systems you might have to use `pgrep` (if available) or something like `ps | grep "^$pid "`.

Comment: Never found better. you can add a timeout parameter that kill -15 then kill -9 if the process get stuck ...

Comment: Better yet, kill -15, kill -2, kill -1, then maybe kill -9.

Comment: **Caution**: This does not always work, as [pointed out below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407912/780703) by [mp3foley](http://stackoverflow.com/users/231760/mp3foley). See that comment and [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11719943/780703) for the details.

Comment: **Caution 2** (On zombies): The follow-up comment by Teddy above is not sufficient yet, since they may be zombies. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11719943/780703) for a Linux solution.

Comment: Doesn't this solution risk a race condition? While sleeping in `sleep 0.5`, process with `$pid` may die and another process may be created with the same `$pid`. And we will end up waiting for 2 different processes (or even more) with the same `$pid`.

Comment: @ks1322 Yes, this code indeed has a race condition in it.

Comment: Aren't PIDs usually sequentially generated? What is the likeliness of the count wrapping around in one second?

Comment: @esmiralha depends on how busy the system is and `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`, but yes normally unlikely.  The bigger problem is if you are waiting for multiple pids, and by the time the first pid has been waited for, the second/later pids are replaced. For multiple pids you probably want multiple async waits, that are all waited for.

Comment: Note that `kill` *is* a shell builtin.

Comment: downvote because it doesn't always work, as indicated in comments.

Comment: You can work around the race condition by checking the process's start time. If the start time is the same, the pid must refer to the same process.

Answer (score 57):

I found "kill -0" does not work if the process is owned by root (or other), so I used pgrep and came up with:

```
while pgrep -u root process_name > /dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

This would have the disadvantage of probably matching zombie processes.

Comment: Good observation. In POSIX, the system call ``kill(pid, sig=0)`` fails if the caller process doesn't have a privilege to kill. Thus /bin/kill -0 and "kill -0" (bash built-in) fail too under the same condition.

Answer (score 33):

This bash script loop ends if the process does not exist, or it's a zombie.

```
PID=<pid to watch>
while s=`ps -p $PID -o s=` && [[ "$s" && "$s" != 'Z' ]]; do
    sleep 1
done
```

**EDIT**: The above script [was given below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058047/wait-for-any-process-to-finish/11719943#comment66049781_11719943)  by [Rockallite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2293304/rockallite). Thanks!

My orignal answer below works for Linux, relying on `procfs` i.e. `/proc/`. I don't know its portability:

```
while [[ ( -d /proc/$PID ) && ( -z `grep zombie /proc/$PID/status` ) ]]; do
    sleep 1
done
```

It's not limited to shell, but OS's themselves do not have system calls to watch non-child process termination.

Comment: Nice one. Although I had to surround ``grep /proc/$PID/status`` with double quotes (`bash: test: argument expected`)

Comment: Hum ... just tried it again and it worked. I guess I did something wrong last time.

Comment: Or ```while s=`ps -p $PID -o s=` && [[ "$s" && "$s" != 'Z' ]]; do sleep 1; done```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in BusyBox - in its `ps`, neither `-p` or `s=` are supported

Answer (score 16):

FreeBSD and Solaris have this handy `pwait(1)` utility, which does exactly, what you want.

I believe, other modern OSes also have the necessary system calls too (MacOS, for example, implements BSD's `kqueue`), but not all make it available from command-line.

Comment: `> BSD and Solaris`:

Inspecting the three big BSDs that come to mind; neither OpenBSD nor NetBSD have this function (in their man pages), only FreeBSD does, as you can easily check on [man.openbsd.org](http://man.openbsd.org).

Comment: Seems like you are right. Mea culpa... They all implement `kqueue`, so compiling FreeBSD's `pwait(1)` would be trivial, however. Why wouldn't the other BSD's import the feature escapes me...

Comment: `plink me@oracle box -pw redacted "pwait 6998";email -b -s "It's done" etc` just allowed me to go home now instead of hours from now.

Answer (score 12):

From the bash manpage

```
   wait [n ...]
          Wait for each specified process and return its termination  status
          Each  n  may be a process ID or a job specification; if a
          job spec is given, all processes  in  that  job's  pipeline  are
          waited  for.  If n is not given, all currently active child processes
          are waited for, and the return  status  is  zero.   If  n
          specifies  a  non-existent  process or job, the return status is
          127.  Otherwise, the return status is the  exit  status  of  the
          last process or job waited for.
```

Comment: That's true but it can only wait for child of the current shell. You can't wait for **any** process.

Comment: @gumik : *"If n is not given, all currently active child processes are waited for"* . This works perfectly..`wait` without args will block the process until *any child* processes finish. 
Honestly, I don't see any point to wait for *any* process since there's always systemprocesses going on.

Comment: @coderofsalvation ( sleep 10 & sleep 3 & wait ) takes 10 seconds to return: wait without args will block until ALL child processes finish. OP wants to be notified when the first child (or nominated) process finishes.

Comment: Also doesn't work if the process isn't backgrounded or foregrounded (on Solaris, Linux, or Cygwin).  ex.  `sleep 1000` `ctrl-z` `wait [sleep pid]` returns immediately

Answer (score 7):

All these solutions are tested in Ubuntu 14.04:

**Solution 1 (by using ps command):** 
Just to add up to Pierz answer, I would suggest:

```
while ps axg | grep -vw grep | grep -w process_name > /dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

In this case, `grep -vw grep` ensures that grep matches only process_name and not grep itself. It has the advantage of supporting the cases where the process_name is not at the end of a line at `ps axg`.

**Solution 2 (by using top command and process name):**

```
while [[ $(awk '$12=="process_name" {print $0}' <(top -n 1 -b)) ]]; do sleep 1; done
```

Replace `process_name` with the process name that appears in `top -n 1 -b`. Please keep the quotation marks.

To see the list of processes that you wait for them to be finished, you can run:

```
while : ; do p=$(awk '$12=="process_name" {print $0}' <(top -n 1 -b)); [[ $b ]] || break; echo $p; sleep 1; done
```

**Solution 3 (by using top command and process ID):**

```
while [[ $(awk '$1=="process_id" {print $0}' <(top -n 1 -b)) ]]; do sleep 1; done
```

Replace `process_id` with the process ID of your program.

Comment: Downvote: the long `grep -v grep` pipeline is a massive antipattern, and this presupposes that you don't have unrelated processes with the same name.  If you know the PIDs instead, this could be adapted to a properly working solution.

Comment: Thanks tripleee for the comment. I added the flag `-w` to avoid the problem of `grep -v grep` _to some extent_. I also added two more solutions based on your comment.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, so it seems the answer is -- no, there is no built in tool.

After setting `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` to `0`, it is possible to use the `strace` program. Further switches can be used to make it silent, so that it really waits passively:

```
strace -qqe '' -p <PID>
```

Comment: Nice one! It seems though that it is not possible to attach to a given PID from two different places (I get `Operation not permitted` for the second strace instance); can you confirm that?

Comment: @eudoxos Yes, the manpage for ptrace says: `(...)"tracee" always means "(one) thread"` (and I confirm the error you mention). To let more processes wait this way, you'd have to make a chain.

Comment: I don't have the `ptrace_scope` parameter (kernel 4.14) but  this is also a busy-wait solution. From looking at the source I cannot even see a delay built in the loop (but the process does use very little CPU).

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, I solved the issue killing the process and then waiting for each process to finish using the PROC filesystem:

```
while [ -e /proc/${pid} ]; do sleep 0.1; done
```

Comment: polling is very bad, you could get a visit from the police :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no builtin feature to wait for any process to finish.

You could send `kill -0` to any PID found, so you don't get puzzled by zombies and stuff that will still be visible in `ps` (while still retrieving the PID list using `ps`).

Answer (score 3):

### Blocking solution

Use the `wait` in a loop, for waiting for terminate all processes:

```
function anywait()
{

    for pid in "$@"
    do
        wait $pid
        echo "Process $pid terminated"
    done
    echo 'All processes terminated'
}
```

This function will exits immediately, when all processes was terminated. This is the most efficient solution.

### Non-blocking solution

Use the `kill -0` in a loop, for waiting for terminate all processes + do anything between checks:

```
function anywait_w_status()
{
    for pid in "$@"
    do
        while kill -0 "$pid"
        do
            echo "Process $pid still running..."
            sleep 1
        done
    done
    echo 'All processes terminated'
}
```

The reaction time decreased to `sleep` time, because have to prevent high CPU usage.

**A realistic usage:**

Waiting for terminate all processes + inform user about **all** running PIDs.

```
function anywait_w_status2()
{
    while true
    do
        alive_pids=()
        for pid in "$@"
        do
            kill -0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null \
                && alive_pids+="$pid "
        done

        if [ ${#alive_pids[@]} -eq 0 ]
        then
            break
        fi

        echo "Process(es) still running... ${alive_pids[@]}"
        sleep 1
    done
    echo 'All processes terminated'
}
```

### Notes

These functions getting PIDs via arguments by `$@` as BASH array.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to both kill a process and wait for it finish, this can be achieved with [`killall(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html) (based on process names), and [`start-stop-daemon(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html) (based on a pidfile).

To kill all processes matching `someproc` and wait for them to die:

```
killall someproc --wait             # wait forever until matching processes die
timeout 10s killall someproc --wait # timeout after 10 seconds
```

(Unfortunately, there's no direct equivalent of `--wait` with `kill` for a specific pid).

To kill a process based on a pidfile `/var/run/someproc.pid` using signal `SIGINT`, while waiting for it to finish, with `SIGKILL` being sent after 20 seconds of timeout, use:

```
start-stop-daemon --stop --signal INT --retry 20 --pidfile /var/run/someproc.pid
```

Comment: You need to install `psmisc` if `killall` not found.

Answer (score 1):

Use inotifywait to monitor some file that gets closed, when your process terminates. Example (on Linux):

```
yourproc >logfile.log & disown
inotifywait -q -e close logfile.log
```

-e specifies the event to wait for, -q means minimal output only on termination. In this case it will be:

```
logfile.log CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE
```

A single wait command can be used to wait for multiple processes:

```
yourproc1 >logfile1.log & disown
yourproc2 >logfile2.log & disown
yourproc3 >logfile3.log & disown
inotifywait -q -e close logfile1.log logfile2.log logfile3.log
```

The output string of inotifywait will tell you, which process terminated. This only works with 'real' files, not with something in /proc/

Answer (score 1):

Rauno Palosaari's solution for `Timeout in Seconds` `Darwin`, is an excellent workaround for a UNIX-like OS that does not have GNU `tail` (it is not specific to `Darwin`).  But, depending on the age of the UNIX-like operating system, the command-line offered is more complex than necessary, and can fail:

```
lsof -p $pid +r 1m%s -t | grep -qm1 $(date -v+${timeout}S +%s 2>/dev/null || echo INF)
```

On at least one old UNIX, the `lsof` argument `+r 1m%s` fails (even for a superuser):

```
lsof: can't read kernel name list.
```

The `m%s` is an output format specification.  A simpler post-processor does not require it.  For example, the following command waits on PID 5959 for up to five seconds:

```
lsof -p 5959 +r 1 | awk '/^=/ { if (T++ >= 5) { exit 1 } }'
```

In this example, if PID 5959 exits of its own accord before the five seconds elapses, `${?}` is `0`.  If not `${?}` returns `1` after five seconds.

It may be worth expressly noting that in `+r 1`, the `1` is the poll interval (in seconds), so it may be changed to suit the situation.

Answer (score -1):

On a system like OSX you might not have pgrep so you can try this appraoch, when looking for processes by name:

```
while ps axg | grep process_name$ > /dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

The `$` symbol at the end of the process name ensures that grep matches only process_name to the end of line in the ps output and not itself.

Comment: Horrible: There may be multiple processes with that name _somewhere in the command line_, your own grep included. Instead of redirecting to `/dev/null`, `-q` should be used with `grep`. Another instance of the process may have started while your loop was sleeping and you'll never know...

Comment: I'm not sure why you singled out this answer as 'Horrible' - as a similar approach has been suggested by others? Whilst the `-q` suggestion is valid, as I mentioned in my answer specifically the terminating `$` means grep will not match the name "somewhere in the command line" nor will it match itself. Have u actually tried it on OSX?