# Python subprocess.check_call(["wine"]..) has a synchronization issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, race-condition, wine

I have a python script which uses `subprocess.check_call` to launch Wine (Windows Emulator on Linux), then the wine launches `Z:\\Program Files (x86)\\PeaZip\\peazip.exe`.

Firstly, when I tested this python script in debugging mode `python3 -u -m ipdb unpack_archive.py`, and set breakpoint around wine launch and run statements step by step, the Wine runs `peazip.exe` successfully. That is, peazip successfully extract the PEA archive on Linux.

However, when I tested this python script not in debugging mode `python3 unpack_archive.py`, then I find peazip.exe doesn't extract PEA archive successfully. So I suspect there is a synchronization problem in wine or python subprocess.check_call().

Now my workaround is, inserting `time.sleep(1.0)` after launching wine :

```
elif 'PEA archive' in ftype:
    if splitext(arcname)[1] != '.pea':
        tmpfile = os.path.join(tmpdir, basename(arcname))+'.pea'
    else:
        tmpfile = os.path.join(tmpdir, basename(arcname))
    shutil.copy(arcname, tmpfile)
    subprocess.check_call(["wine", "/home/acteam/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/PeaZip/peazip.exe",
        "-ext2here", to_wine_path(tmpfile)])
    import time
    time.sleep(1.0) # if we don't sleep, then peazip.exe won't extract file successfully 
    os.remove(tmpfile)
    copy_without_symlink(tmpdir, outdir)
```

I checked the [wine manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wine), it doesn't mention anything about synchronization. I also checked [subprocess.check_call()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call). The document explicitly says the check_call() will wait for the command completed.

I don't want this workaround, because if the PEA archive file is very large, then the timeout value for sleep() must be larger, and we can't predict the sufficient timeout value before running it.

---

I referred to [@jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45638364/524781)'s suggestion. Use subprocess.check_output() instead of check_call()

```
    elif 'PEA archive' in ftype:
        if splitext(arcname)[1] != '.pea':
            tmpfile = os.path.join(tmpdir, basename(arcname))+'.pea'
        else:
            tmpfile = os.path.join(tmpdir, basename(arcname))
        shutil.copy(arcname, tmpfile)
        subprocess.check_output(["wine", "/home/acteam/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/PeaZip/peazip.exe",
            "-ext2here", to_wine_path(tmpfile)])
        os.remove(tmpfile)
        copy_without_symlink(splitext(tmpfile)[0], outdir)
```

I tested it with `python3 unpack_archive.py Kevin.pea`, which is a 2.0GB PEA archive. The extraction process costs 4 minutes 16 seconds. Three subfiles are unpacked successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the `wine` executable is not the actual emulator - it just launches a background process called `wineserver` if it's not already running, tells it to run the Windows program, and then immediately exits itself - quite possibly before the Windows program has even started running.

One of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205856/waiting-for-wine-to-finish-running) suggests that piping the output of `wine` to another program will delay things until the Windows program actually exits.  In Python terms, this would be equivalent to using `check_output()` instead of `check_call()`, although I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: Good. I tried to use `wineserver --foreground`. I found that after `peazip.exe` completed extraction, the `wineserver` will also terminate. 
I launch `wineserver --foreground` before launch `wine`, and wait until `wineserver` subprocess termination.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using advisory locking to block until the process has exited:

```
lockfile=open(tmpfile, 'a')
subprocess.check_call([
         "wine", "/home/acteam/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/PeaZip/peazip.exe",
        "-ext2here", to_wine_path(tmpfile)],
    preexec_fn=lambda: fcntl.flock(lockfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX),
    close_fds=False)
fcntl.flock(lockfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
```

Here, our `preexec_fn` (run after we've `fork()`ed off the subprocess but before `wine` has been started) grabs a lock, and after `check_call()` has returned, we then try to grab that lock ourselves -- which will block if it's not yet released.

(Note that you'll need to be sure that wine doesn't close that file descriptor itself prior to program exit; if it does, one way to avoid that is to create the lock on a descriptor passed as stdin, stdout or stderr).

Comment: I tried your sample code, but I encounter this exception:
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unpack_archive.py", line 258, in <module>
    main()
  File "unpack_archive.py", line 251, in main
    for f,sha1 in unpack_archive(arcname, outdir):
  File "unpack_archive.py", line 169, in unpack_archive
    close_fds=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 556, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
subprocess.SubprocessError: Exception occurred in preexec_fn.
`

Comment: That's not enough detail -- I need the actual exception. You might consider replacing the lambda with a real function that prints a stack trace before raising.

Comment: I modified lambda with a real function. The result is the second `fcntl.flock(lockfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX)` doesn't wait until peazip execution completion.
It still can't resolve race condition.

Comment: I don't suppose there was already a `wineserver` running during the test? (Otherwise, it would have had to close all preopened FDs to avoid holding the lock... which, to be fair, is quite possibly happening).