# Get exit code from non-child process in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, process

Good day! I have a process which was created via `posix_spawn` function. How can I get his exit code?

I know about `waitpid()` function but it returns status for child process. Also if process still a live and I will call `waitpid()` function then I will receive right information what this process isn't closed yet.

Here is my current code:

```
int GetExitCode()
{
  int status;
  int rtn = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
  if (rtn > 0) // still live
  {
    return -1;
  }

  rtn = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
  if (rtn != -1 || errno != ECHILD) 
  {
     // Here I got rtn = -1 and errno #10
  }

  if (WIFEXITED(status))
  {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }

  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

But how I can check exit status for non-child process? Thanks!

Updated. My new code:

```
int GetExitCode()
{
      int status = 0;

      int rtn = kill(pid, 0);
      if (rtn == -1 && errno == ESRCH)
      {
          return 0;
      }

      rtn = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);

      if (rtn == 0) // still live
      {
        return 0;
      }

      std::cout << "Probably success. Errno: " << errno << ". StrError: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
      if (WIFEXITED(status))
      {
        return 1;
      }

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `posix_spawn` function returns a process ID just as `fork` does, which means you can use the normal `wait` family of functions. In fact, the created process *is* a child of your process, just like when you create a process with `fork`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I think that should be an answer. The whole basis of this question seems to be that OP is confused about what "child process" means.

Comment: If that is true then why waitpid returns Error code 10 "No child processes" ? I expected to see termination status... where I made mistake? Thanks

Comment: Can you please add some code to your question to show what you're doing? A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be perfect.

Comment: Sorry, first post updated

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second call to waitpid, the first got the status (you can wait for a process only once).

Comment: So, if I want to check if process still a live I must check it by kill function? As this described in that question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157700/how-to-wait-for-exit-of-non-children-processes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two-fold: First your check if the process is still alive or not is wrong. From the [`waitpid` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) about the return value:

> if WNOHANG was specified and one or more child(ren) specified by pid exist, but have not yet changed state, then 0 is returned.

Since you check for larger than zero, that means you return `-1` when the process has exited.

The second problem is that you call `waitpid` twice. If the process has exited, then you already "reaped" it with the first call which is why the second call gives you an error, since the child process no longer exists.