# How to properly wait for an event/process to finish not being the parent?

Tags: linux, go, freebsd, kqueue

I am using [GO](http://golang.org) to check if a process (not been parent) has ben terminated, basically something like the [pwait](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pwait) command in [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org) but written in go.

Currently I am trying a `for loop` with a `kill -0`, but I notice that the CPU usage is very high **99%** with this approach, here is the code:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        fmt.Printf("usage: %s pid", os.Args[0])
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    pid, err := strconv.ParseInt(os.Args[1], 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    process, err := os.FindProcess(int(pid))

    err = process.Signal(syscall.Signal(0))
    for err == nil {
        err = process.Signal(syscall.Signal(0))
        time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) 
    }
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Any idea of how to improve or properly implement this.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Adding a `sleep` within the loop like suggested, helps reducing the load.

From the provided links, seems to be possible to attach to the existing pid, I will give a try [PtraceAttach](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#PtraceAttach) but don't know if this may have side effects, any idea?

As suggested I was available to use [kqueue](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?kqueue):

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) != 2 {
        fmt.Printf("usage: %s pid", os.Args[0])
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    pid, err := strconv.ParseInt(os.Args[1], 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    process, _ := os.FindProcess(int(pid))

    kq, err := syscall.Kqueue()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    ev1 := syscall.Kevent_t{
        Ident:  uint64(process.Pid),
        Filter: syscall.EVFILT_PROC,
        Flags:  syscall.EV_ADD,
        Fflags: syscall.NOTE_EXIT,
        Data:   0,
        Udata:  nil,
    }

    for {
        events := make([]syscall.Kevent_t, 1)
        n, err := syscall.Kevent(kq, []syscall.Kevent_t{ev1}, events, nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error creating kevent")
        }
        if n > 0 {
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("fin")
}
```

Works fine, but wondering how to implement/achieve the same on linux since I think `kqueue` not available on it, any ideas ?

Comment: Some ideas from this question: [How to wait for exit of non-children processes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1157700)

Comment: Put a short sleep in your for loop. Linux doesn't provide an efficient way to do this

Comment: The `kqueue` API is usable from `go` (in the `syscall` package), and if portability is not required, beyond *BSD and Darwin, then the BSD `pwait` utility could be translated into `go`.

Comment: Again, there's no direct equivalent on linux. If you want to use ptrace, all the relavent details are in the [ptrace man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html). That's going to be much more complicated with more overhead than occasionally polling the PID. Granted there's only one race to attach via ptrace, but a possible race for every individual poll, but there's usually a better way to do these things entirely.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to use the netlink proc connector, which is a socket the kernel uses to let userspace know about different process events. The [official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/connector/connector.txt) is somewhat lacking, although there are a couple of [good examples](http://users.suse.com/~krahmer/exec-notify.c) in C which are probably better to read.

The main caveat to using the proc connector is the process must be run as root. If running your program as a non-root user is a requirement, you should consider other options, such as periodically polling `/proc` to watch for changes. Any approach which uses polling, as others have pointed out, is susceptible to a race condition if the process is terminated and another one is started with the same PID in between polls.

Anyway, to use the proc connector in Go, we will have to do some translation from C. Specifically, we need to define the `proc_event` and `exit_proc_event` structs from [cn_proc.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/cn_proc.h#L45), and the `cn_msg` and `cb_id` structs from [connector.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/connector.h).

```
// CbID corresponds to cb_id in connector.h
type CbID struct {
    Idx uint32
    Val uint32
}

// CnMsg corresponds to cn_msg in connector.h
type CnMsg struct {
    ID CbID
    Seq uint32
    Ack uint32
    Len uint16
    Flags uint16
}

// ProcEventHeader corresponds to proc_event in cn_proc.h
type ProcEventHeader struct {
    What uint32
    CPU uint32
    Timestamp uint64
}

// ExitProcEvent corresponds to exit_proc_event in cn_proc.h
type ExitProcEvent struct {
    ProcessPid uint32
    ProcessTgid uint32
    ExitCode uint32
    ExitSignal uint32
}
```

We also need to make a netlink socket and call bind.

```
sock, err := unix.Socket(unix.AF_NETLINK, unix.SOCK_DGRAM, unix.NETLINK_CONNECTOR)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("socket: %v", err)
    return
}

addr := &unix.SockaddrNetlink{Family: unix.AF_NETLINK, Groups: C.CN_IDX_PROC, Pid: uint32(os.Getpid())}
err = unix.Bind(sock, addr)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("bind: %v\n", err)
    return
}
```

Next, we have to send the `PROC_CN_MCAST_LISTEN` message to the kernel to let it know we want to receive events. We can import this directly from C, where it's defined as an enum, to save some typing, and put it in a function since we will have to call it again with `PROC_CN_MCAST_IGNORE` when we are done receiving data from the kernel.

```
// #include <linux/cn_proc.h>
// #include <linux/connector.h>
import "C"

func send(sock int, msg uint32) error {
    destAddr := &unix.SockaddrNetlink{Family: unix.AF_NETLINK, Groups: C.CN_IDX_PROC, Pid: 0} // the kernel
    cnMsg := CnMsg{}
    header := unix.NlMsghdr{
        Len: unix.NLMSG_HDRLEN + uint32(binary.Size(cnMsg) + binary.Size(msg)),
        Type: uint16(unix.NLMSG_DONE),
        Flags: 0,
        Seq: 1,
        Pid: uint32(unix.Getpid()),
    }
    msg.ID = CbID{Idx: C.CN_IDX_PROC, Val: C.CN_VAL_PROC}
    msg.Len = uint16(binary.Size(msg))
    msg.Ack = 0
    msg.Seq = 1
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, header.Len))
    binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, header)
    binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, cnMsg)
    binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, msg)

    return unix.Sendto(sock, buf.Bytes(), 0, destAddr)
}
```

After we let the kernel know we're ready to receive events, we can receive them on the socket we're created. Once we receive them, we need to parse them, and check for relevant data. We only care about messages that meet the following criteria:

- Come from the kernel
- Have a header type of `NLMSG_DONE`
- Have a `proc_event_header.what` value of `PROC_EVENT_EXIT`
- Match our PID

If they meet these criteria, we can extract the relevant process information into a `proc_event_exit` struct, which contains the PID of the process.

```
for {
    p := make([]byte, 1024)
    nr, from, err := unix.Recvfrom(sock, p, 0)

    if sockaddrNl, ok := from.(*unix.SockaddrNetlink); !ok || sockaddrNl.Pid != 0 {
        continue
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Recvfrom: %v\n", err)
        continue
    }

    if nr < unix.NLMSG_HDRLEN {
        continue
    }

    // the sys/unix package doesn't include the ParseNetlinkMessage function
    nlmessages, err := syscall.ParseNetlinkMessage(p[:nr])

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ParseNetlinkMessage: %v\n", err)
        continue
    }

    for _, m := range(nlmessages) {
        if m.Header.Type == unix.NLMSG_DONE {
            buf := bytes.NewBuffer(m.Data)
            msg := &CnMsg{}
            hdr := &ProcEventHeader{}
            binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, msg)
            binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, hdr)

            if hdr.What == C.PROC_EVENT_EXIT {
                event := &ExitProcEvent{}
                binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, event)
                pid := int(event.ProcessTgid)
                fmt.Printf("%d just exited.\n", pid)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A full code example is [here](https://gist.github.com/pmalmgren/e3498ee4e137a11f2db9330b191afa9f).

Comment: This is a great reply! Just wanted to say that in 2018, a Go package which does all this popped up: https://github.com/fearful-symmetry/garlic