# Wait for a program (non-child) to finish and execute a command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a program running on a remote computer which shouldn't be stopped. I need to track when this program is stopped and immediately execute a command. PID is known. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have control on how the program start? Do you want the execution on already run program or on the next execution?

Comment: @RomeoNinov This program is already running, I need to wait when it stops.

Comment: Something like can do the work. But its ugly and power consuming: while true 
do
if [ "$(ps -efl|grep $PIDN|wc -l)" -lt 1 ]
then <exec code>; break
fi
sleep 5
done

Comment: @RomeoNinov I think that wouldn't work on `a remote computer` as the OP said

Comment: @ChatterOne it will, I'm using ssh and screen

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks, I launched it, let's wait till the program stops :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov I meant that you'd need to launch SSH first, of course, which is not included in the command you suggested

Comment: @ChatterOne, yes, and create the script. And run it (it can be in background)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You [cannot `wait` for non-child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157700/how-to-wait-for-exit-of-non-children-processes#1157739).

Probably the most efficient way in a shell would be to poll using the exit code of `kill -0 <pid>` to check if the process still exists:

```
while kill -0 $PID 2>/dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

This is both simpler and more efficient than any approaches involving `ps` and `grep`. However, it only works if your user has permission to send signals to that process.

Comment: I agree that `kill -0` is a good way to check for a running process, with one caveat -- it only succeeds if the current user has permission to send signals to that process.

Answer (score 0):

Code like this can do the work (to be run on remote computer)

```
while true 
do
if [ "$(ps -efl|grep $PIDN|grep -v grep|wc -l)" -lt 1 ]
then <exec code>; break
fi
sleep 5
done
```

It expect the variable PIDN to contain the PID.

P.S. I know the code is ugly and power hungry

EDIT: it is possible to use `-p` in `ps` to avoid one grep

```
while true 
do
if [ "$(ps -p $PIDN|wc -l)" -lt 2 ]
then <exec code>; break
fi
sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Now sure how portable it would be, but at least on the BSD version of `ps` there's an option `-p` to display only a specific process

Comment: @ChatterOne, on linux `ps` you have also `-p` (or `p`) option to select one pid. But on some UNIXes you may not found it. But will add it, thank you for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple way to wait for a process to terminate using the `ps -p PID` strategy:

```
if ps -p "$PID" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Process $PID is running ..."
    while ps -p "$PID" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
        sleep 5
    done
    echo "Process $PID is not running anymore."
fi
```

### Checking for a process by PID

In general, to check for process ownership or permission to kill (send signals to) a proccess, you can use a combination of `ps -p PID` and `kill -0`:

```
if ps -p "$PID" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Process $PID exists!"

    if kill -0 "$PID" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        echo "You can send signals to process $PID, e.g. with 'kill $PID'"
    else
        echo "You do not have permission to send signals to process $PID"
    fi
else
    echo "Process $PID does not exist."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`exitsnoop`** to achieve this.

The `bcc` toolkit implements many excellent monitoring capabilities based on `eBPF`. Among them, **`exitsnoop`** traces process termination, showing the command name and reason for termination,
either an exit or a fatal signal.

```
   It catches processes of all users, processes in containers,  as  well  as  processes  that
   become zombie.

   This  works by tracing the kernel sched_process_exit() function using dynamic tracing, and
   will need updating to match any changes to this function.

   Since this uses BPF, only the root user can use this tool.
```

`exitsnoop` examples:

```
   Trace all process termination
          # exitsnoop

   Trace all process termination, and include timestamps:
          # exitsnoop -t

   Exclude successful exits, only include non-zero exit codes and fatal signals:
          # exitsnoop -x

   Trace PID 181 only:
          # exitsnoop -p 181

   Label each output line with 'EXIT':
          # exitsnoop --label EXIT
```

You can get more information about this tool from the link below：

- Github repo: tools/[exitsnoop](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/exitsnoop.py): Trace process termination (exit and fatal signals). [Examples](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/exitsnoop_example.txt).
- [Linux Extended BPF (eBPF) Tracing Tools](https://www.brendangregg.com/ebpf.html)
- ubuntu manpages: [exitsnoop-bpfcc](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/exitsnoop-bpfcc.8.html)

---

**Another option**

use this project:
https://github.com/stormc/waitforpid