# wait for slurm job steps started in background by a separate program

Tags: bash, slurm, dvc

In the following Slurm batch script, where program `step_one` and `step_two` are meant to run at the same time, the `wait` call is necessary so the job does not terminate before the job steps are done.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
srun --overlap -n1 step_one &
srun --overlap -n2 step_two &
wait
```

The `wait` blocks until all processes run in the background are done. If another program were to launch the processes for which I need to `wait`, how do I achieve the same result? Without going into details about DVC, just believe me that the following launches the same two steps "in the background" and exits before they are done.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
dvc repro
wait  # has no effect ... what would?
```

For those familiar with DVC, here is the pipeline file:

```
stages:
  one:
    cmd: srun --overlap -n1 step_one &
  two:
    cmd: srun --overlap -n1 step_two &
```

Here is the closes I can come, but I feel like I'm doing it wrong:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
dvc repro
while [ $(sstat -n -a -j $SLURM_JOB_ID | wc -l) -gt 1 ]
do
    sleep 10
done
```

Note that `sstat` gives me a job step called "$SLURM_JOB_ID.batch", hence `-gt 1`.

---

Update: Solutions to a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157700/how-to-wait-for-exit-of-non-children-processes/1157739#1157739) problem (that does not involve Slurm) rely on knowing the PID of the non-child processes. To use those, I would at least need the PIDs.

Comment: Some followup notes: (1) Can SLURM not give you PIDs?; (2) Consider having your processes hold lockfiles open (though logfiles or similar would work just as well); you can use tools like `fuser` to search for the PIDs of processes with handles on those files. (3) if your processes are doing network connections, there are also tools like `lsof` or `netstat -ep` or similar that can give you the PID of any processes holding open a given socket. (4) while lockfiles are a last-resort approach, they _are_ an approach: `cmd: foo & foo_pid=$!` lets you write `$foo_pid` to a file.

Comment: ...that said, I think you've made your point that someone who knows slurm might be able to add a tool-specific approach, and thus that the tool-agnostic duplicate isn't a great fit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for ideas. Working on `$!` to file approach, but `wait` is complaining that "pid 0123456 is not a child of this shell". Hoping for a Slurm solution!

Comment: Right, you can't use the PID with `wait` for reasons the (previously-tagged, slurm-unaware) duplicate explains, but the duplicate has solutions that don't involve `wait`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-answer with my current solution.

My difficulty using DVC with Slurm jobs is that DVC runs stage commands serially (unless you get into queuing experiments, which introduces celery, which would be another queue on top of Slurm ... yikes.). If the stage commands run in the background, however, DVC will chug merrily along. But, you now have to manually enforce the DAG. I did this with advisory file system locking. You also don't want to run DVC commit until the backgrounded commands have completed.

Here's a pipeline with three stages (minimal working examples of `<CMD>` given below), note that the DAG allows stages `one` and `three` to run in parallel while `two` must run after `one`.

```
stages:
  one:
    cmd: flock lock/a <ONE> &
    outs:
    - one.txt
  two:
    cmd: flock lock/a <TWO> &
    deps:
    - one.txt
    outs:
    - two.txt
  three:
    cmd: flock lock/b <THREE> &
    outs:
    - three.txt
```

The `lock/a` and `lock/b` files are created by the `flock` command and correspond to the two separate branches of the DAG. Using `flock` may not be the ultimate solution; the release order of multiple stage commands waiting on the same lock is unclear to me.

Wrap your `dvc repro` command in a script something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
mkdir lock
dvc repro --no-commit
for item in lock/*
do
    flock $item rm $item
done
rmdir lock
```

This script would be your `sbatch` submission script, but I'm leaving all that out. I'll also leave out the `srun` part of the minimal working example below, but you'd need them for Slurm in your stage commands.

When you `source job.sh` (or `sbatch job.sh`), the commands all fire into the background and DVC exits. The flock mechanism takes over for releasing commands to run, and the script exits after all locks are released (and cleaned up). You would then run `dvc commit`.

Here's an example that works without Slurm:

```
stages:
  one:
    cmd: flock lock/a ./stamp.sh </dev/null >one.txt &
    outs:
    - one.txt
  two:
    cmd: flock lock/a ./stamp.sh <one.txt >two.txt &
    deps:
    - one.txt
    outs:
    - two.txt
  three:
    cmd: flock lock/b ./stamp.sh </dev/null >three.txt &
    outs:
    - three.txt
```

With executable `stamp.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "time now is $(date +'%T')"
read line
echo $line | sed -e "s/now is/then was/"
sleep 10
```

Some results:

```
% source job.sh
Running stage 'three':                                                
> flock lock/b ./stamp.sh </dev/null >three.txt &
WARNING: 'three.txt' is empty.                                        

Running stage 'one':
> flock lock/a ./stamp.sh </dev/null >one.txt &
WARNING: 'one.txt' is empty.                                          

Running stage 'two':
> flock lock/a ./stamp.sh <one.txt >two.txt &
WARNING: 'two.txt' is empty.                                          
Updating lock file 'dvc.lock'

To track the changes with git, run:

    git add dvc.lock

To enable auto staging, run:

    dvc config core.autostage true
Use `dvc push` to send your updates to remote storage.
% grep "time" *.txt
one.txt:time now is 11:38:58
three.txt:time now is 11:38:58
two.txt:time now is 11:39:08
two.txt:time then was 11:38:58
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. Unfortunately I don't know a better solution. In DVC it can be solved like this I think (just an idea from the top of my head). (It's not a complete solution! You would need to make the `wait` stage depend on the stages `one` and `two` similar to the dependency on `zero` so that `wait` doesn't start before them):

```yaml
stages:
  zero:
    cmd:
      - rm -f res* || true
      - echo date > zero
    outs:
      - zero
    always_changed: true

  one:
    deps:
      - zero
    cmd: (./process1.sh; echo $? > res1) &

  two:
    deps:
      - zero
    cmd: (./process2.sh; echo $? > res2) &

  wait:
    deps:
      - zero
    cmd: ./wait.sh
```

where `wait.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -eux

while [ ! -f res1 ] || [ ! -f res2 ] ; do sleep 1; done
```

It becomes ugly pretty quick tbh :( Primarily since there is no mechanism for a stage to depend on another stage w/o an explicit out/dep between them.

If you can make stages output files in some other way in your case (e.g. create a file when they just start) that would simplify the logic a bit.