# Linux: start a script after another has finished

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I read the answer for this issue from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485776/start-script-after-another-one-already-running-finishes)
in Stackoverflow.com. But I am so new in writing shell script that I did something wrong. The following are my scripts:

testscript:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
pid=$(ps -opid= -C csh testscript1)
while [ -d /proc/$pid ] ; do
    sleep 1
done && csh testscript2

exit
```

testscript1:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
/usr/bin/firefox
exit
```

testscript2:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
echo Done
exit
```

The purpose is for testscript to call testscript1 first; once testscript1 already finish (which means the firefox called in script1 is closed) testscript will call testscript2. However I got this result after running testscript:

```
$ csh testscript
Illegal variable name.
```

Please help me with this issue. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you didn't notice that the scripts you found were written for bash, not csh, but
you're trying to process them with the csh interpreter.

It looks like you've misunderstood what the original code was trying to do -- it was
intended to monitor an already-existing process, by looking up its process id using the process name.

You seem to be trying to start the first process from inside the `ps` command.  But
in that case, there's no need for you to do anything so complicated -- all you need
is:

```
#!/bin/csh
csh testscript1
csh testscript2
```

Unless you go out of your way to run one of the scripts in the background,
the second script will not run until the first script is finished.

Although this has nothing to do with your problem, csh is more oriented toward 
interactive use; for script writing, [it's considered a poor choice](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot), so you might be 
better off learning bash instead.

Comment: I actually did try bash file and it said `ps: illegal argument: ./testscript1.sh`, and execute testscript2.sh

Comment: I've updated my answer.  The original script was doing something rather different that what you seem to need.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. The script that you recommend me works well in Linux. I tried this before in Mac OS X and got the result that  'Done' was printed right after the Firefox was open. And I didn't try it again in Linux. Anyway working in Linux is what I need now. But could you please explain to me why it didn't work that way in Mac OS X? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this line is not CSH:

```
pid=$(ps -opid= -C csh testscript1)
```

In general in csh you define variables like this:

```
set pid=...
```

I am not sure what the $() syntax is, perhaps back ticks woudl work as a replacement:

```
set pid=`ps -opid= -C csh testscript1`
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and received this: `ERROR: TTY could not be found.` and a list of options for using ps

Answer (score 0):

Try,

below script will check testscript1's pid, if it is not found then it will execute testscirpt2

```
 sp=$(ps -ef | grep testscript1 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
 /bin/ls -l /proc/ | grep $sp > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0 || /bin/csh testscript2
```