# How to wait for any job to finished using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, process, background, jobs

I have multiple scripts that I launch in background.
What I want to do is to launch another script when any of previous has finished execution (theese scripts have unpredictable execution time, so I don't know which of them finish first).

Something like this

```
exec ./MyScript1.sh &
exec ./MyScript2.sh &
exec ./MyScript3.sh &

#Now wait until any of them finishes and launch ./MyScript4.sh
#What do I have to do?
```

I've read about wait shell builtin but it waits for all jobs to finish, and I need when **only one of them** does this.
Any ideas?

Comment: you canrefer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485776/start-script-after-another-one-already-running-finishes)

Comment: Use [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Comment: First link is not useful for me as it suggests polling. However this takes time, and my scripts are speed tests, and loosing a second is not an option.

Comment: Can you not just have them run another script when they finish ?

Comment: What do `MyScript{1,2,3}.sh` provide that `MyScript4.sh` requires, that it doesn't matter which one provides it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a long-running process which each of the three background processes will try to kill once they've completed, then wait for that process to die before running `MyScript4.sh`. This does require that you not use `exec` to execute `MyScript{1,2,3}.sh`, so hopefully that is not a hard requirement.

```
# Assuming that 100,000 seconds is long enough 
# for at least one bg job to complete
sleep 100000 & sleep_pid=$!

{ MyScript1.sh; kill $sleep_pid 2>/dev/null; } &
{ MyScript2.sh; kill $sleep_pid 2>/dev/null; } &
{ MyScript3.sh; kill $sleep_pid 2>/dev/null; } &
wait $sleep_pid
MyScript4.sh
```

A similar option is to use a blocking read on a named pipe. (As presented, this has the additional drawback that only one of the background jobs can finish, as the other two will block trying to write to `starter` until somebody reads two more lines from it.)

```
mkfifo starter
{ MyScript1.sh; echo foo > starter; } &
{ MyScript2.sh; echo foo > starter; } &
{ MyScript3.sh; echo foo > starter; } &
read < starter && MyScript4.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to start a counter that increment a 1 before the execution of each script and decrement 1 after it finishes. This way you know how many are running simultaneously. Then you just need to watch where this value is higher or lower than a certain threshold (lets say 3) and run an additional process.

let me give an example:

run_scripts.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#allowed simultaneous scripts 
num_scripts=3

#initialize counter
script_counter=0
echo $script_counter
echo $script_counter > ./script_counter

# for loop to run the scripts
for i in `seq 1 10`
do
    ./script1.sh &
    sleep 0.1
    script_counter=`head -n 1 ./script_counter`
    echo $script_counter

    # wait until the number of running scripts is lower than 4
    while [ $script_counter -gt $num_scripts  ]
    do
        sleep 0.5
        script_counter=`head -n 1 ./script_counter`
    done
done
```

script1.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

# increment counter
script_counter=`head -n 1 ./script_counter`
script_counter=$(($script_counter + 1))
echo $script_counter > ./script_counter
#echo $script_counter

# your code goes here
rand_numb=$(($RANDOM%10+1))
sleep $rand_numb
######

# decrement counter
script_counter=`head -n 1 ./script_counter`
script_counter=$(($script_counter - 1))
echo $script_counter > ./script_counter
#echo $script_counter
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines at the end of your `MyScript1-3.sh`

```
if mkdir /tmp/mylock ; then
  ./MyScript4.sh
fi
```

This use `/tmp/mylock` as a lock to synchronize process.
Only the first process that run `mkdir` command is success and get into `if` block.
The others will all fail.