# Interrupt an order like: fg ; next_program

Tags: bash, foreground

I have been reading this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35587710 for the case when you have executed a program with a long execution time and just after that you realize you wanted to execute another program when the first one finish. The solution says use:

```
Ctrl Z
fg ; python next_program.py
```

If what I wanted to execute was badly written due to a typo, i.e., I wrote `fg ; python my_prograM.py` and I wanted to do `fg ; python my_program.py`, how can I cancel the first fg and launch the second one? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original job is still the one that Ctrl-Z would interrupt, and the one that `fg` will resume. Just interrupt as you did before, then type `fg; python my_program.py` to fix the typo. `fg` only restarts the currently suspended job; it doesn't repeat the last shell command line.