# Using while or until to wait until a PID doesn't exist

Tags: bash, process

I have been using Bash to wait until a PID no longer exists. I've tried

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ kill -0 PID > /dev/null 2>&1 ]; do
    //code to kill process
done
//code to execute after process is dead
```

as well as

```
#!/bin/bash
until [ ! kill -0 PID > /dev/null 2>&1 ]; do
    //code to kill process
done
//code to execute after process is dead
```

Both these examples either fail to work, or keep on looping after the process has ended. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you not just use `wait "$PID"`?

Comment: It would return that the PID was not a child of the shell.

Comment: **Unless** the process you watch is _a child process_, there're several pitfalls. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058047/wait-for-any-process-to-finish/1127675#comment24774342_1058047) for the details.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be simply doing:

```
while kill -0 $PID >/dev/null 2>&1
do
    # Code to kill process
done
```

The loop condition tests the exit status of the last command — in this case, `kill`.  The `-0` option (used in the question) doesn't actually send any signal to the process, but it does check whether a signal could be sent — and it can't be sent if the process no longer exists.
(See the POSIX specification of the [`kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) function and the POSIX [`kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) utility.)

The significance of 'last' is that you could write:

```
while sleep 1
      echo Testing again
      kill -0 $PID >/dev/null 2>&1
do
    # Code to kill process
done
```

This too tests the exit status of `kill` (and `kill` alone).

Answer (score 4):

Also you can do in unixes with procfs (almost all except mac os)

```
while test -d /proc/$PID; do
     kill -$SIGNAL $PID
     # optionally
     sleep 0.2
done
```

Comment: I didn't notice that mac doesn't have procfs.