# How to get to know whether the Linux process is running

Tags: linux, bash

Given a pid, for example 29264， how to get to know whether the process is running  ?

Is there any easy way to do that ?

thx

Comment: As a note: usually PID is *not enough* to check whether a particular process is *still* running. If a process exits, its PID can be reused by some other process, so it's usually not a safe assumption. If you aren't spawning many processes of the same name, you could also involve checking the process name. But the best way is through a lock file. But it all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: Let me add one point: *unless* the process you watch is a _child process_, there're several pitfalls. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058047/wait-for-any-process-to-finish/1127675#comment24774342_1058047) for the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get process status:

```
ps -p 29264 > /dev/null; echo $?
```

Answer (score 3):

Process status (`ps`) provides the information you're looking for:

```
ps -p 29264
```

Output in case the process is running (quick example on my Mac, works the same on Linux):

```
PID     TIME       CMD
127     4:54.03    /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
```

Otherwhise:

```
PID     TIME       CMD
```

Comment: Note that on Linux, such a `ps` invocation lists `TTY` as well. You should not try to depend on any particular fields.

Answer (score 3):

`kill -0 29264` ,and inspect the error (if any)

[link to online linux (man 2) manual](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/kill.2.html)

[link to online linux (man 1) manual](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?kill%201)

Comment: excuse me ,what is the meaning of `kill -0 <pid>` , since `kill -l` does not provide the **zero** signal ?

Comment: From The Fine Manual: "Particularly useful signals include HUP, INT, KILL, STOP, CONT, and 0." The meaning of `kill -0` is : perform all the necessary steps for sending a signal, but don't deliver any actual signal to the process. But the error reporting is the same as for a normal signal. See also `man 2 kill`

Comment: Could  you provide a link for that instruction ?