# Preventing cronjobs from overlapping

Tags: linux, cron, queue, spool

I have 3 different jobs set up in crontab (call them jobA, jobB, jobC) that run at different intervals and start at different times during the day.  For example, jobA runs once per hour at 5 mins past the hour, jobB runs every 30 mins at 9 and 39 mins past the hour, and jobC runs every 15 mins.  They are not dependent on each other, but for various reasons they can NOT be running at the same time.

The problem is that sometimes one of the jobs takes a long time to run and another one starts before the first one is done, causing issues.

Is there some way to queue or spool these jobs so that one will not start until the current running one has finished?  I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058047/wait-for-any-process-to-finish) but this does not guarantee that the pending jobs will resume in the same order they were supposed to start.  A queue would be best, but I cannot find anything about how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using `cron`. Cron is used to run a specific command at specific time. You can do it by the solution you proposed, but that adds a lot more complexity.

I suggest, writing/coding the requirement in high level language like `java` and use a mutil-thread program to achieve what you need.

`Control-m` is another scheduling software, with a lot of other features as well. You would be able to integrate the above use-case in it.