# nonblocking wait ${myPid} in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, wait, blocking

I need to start a process in the background, then continue and run other processes.  I want to exit the script as soon as my myBackgroundProcess process ends with non 0 exit code. (or soon ish when i check in the loop).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

nohup myBackgroundProcess &
myPid=$!


for i in {1..30000}; do
   sleep 10
   someProcessDoingStuff
   wait ${myPid}  #this is blocking, but i want to continue the loop
done
```

so I would like some type of non blocking way to check the exit code of a process by its pid, if it has finished.

its is close this issue [WAIT for "any process" to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058047/wait-for-any-process-to-finish)  but not 100% same,  however the issue gives a clue  as to how one might implement your own nonblocking wait

A possible work around

```
$(sleep 10 ; echo $? > exitCode.txt) &
```

any better solutions, or issues with the above.
1 issue is 1 loose the std out of the process.

so i want to start a process in the background, keep its std out err, and have the exit code written to a file.  with out modding the process its self.

Comment: i found this https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-09/msg00005.html

Comment: I would make `myBackgroundProcess` to create a file on exit and check existence of that file (you can put the exist status into the file).

Comment: I like the idea of writing the exit code to file, and checking for the file existing.

Comment: a possible implementation of your idea  $(sleep 10 ; echo $? > exitCode.txt) &

Comment: issue:  I want the std out also

Comment: What is you `myBackgroundProcess `?

Comment: a jvm, controlling, other jvm's on remote boxes via activeMQ jms

Comment: Your Java process has to create that file and put the exit code into it. Your bash script has to monitor the existence of that file and read the code from it. No standard input/output need to be involved

Comment: I would like a way, where the backprocess dose not need to be modified,  I am sure its possible,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116178/discussion-between-gmichael-and-dmc).