# Can I record linux process exit info?

Tags: linux

On my system, some processes always exit, Now I don't know if they exit on their own or if someone kills them.

Can I record linux process exit info?

For example, if I have a process killed by another process, I can see a kill record in a log like `xx pid killed yy pid` or if my process exits itself, I can see `XX PID exit by self`.

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another) might have an answer, or possibly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058047/wait-for-any-process-to-finish/41613532#41613532) might help .. but you might get downvoted on here or have your question closed if you don't have a specific question to any code itself ..

Answer (score 0):

Linux has process accounting -- [acct(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/acct).

If you turn it on, e.g., with the `accton` command, Linux will record some process info into a file each time a process exits. The info does record signal deaths int the `ac_flags` field (though this doesn't distinguish the signal that caused the deatH) and it looks like you could get the complete exit information (as from [wait(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/acct)) from the `ac_exitcode` field. Unfortunately the shipped `dump-acct` command isn't showing it, but I suppose you could show it if you parsed the file from C.

Apart form this feature, in a basic UNIX POSIX system, only process parents can get the exit information their child (`ptrace` too, but `ptrace`-based tracers sort of act like a second parent).

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between `accton` and `history`?