# How to wait on a backgrounded sub-process with `wait` command

Tags: linux, bash

I have two scripts

`foox.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "foox"
./fooy.sh &
pid=${!}
echo "waiting on ${pid}"
timeout 4 wait ${pid}
echo "waited on ${pid} with result ${!}"
```

and `fooy.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "fooy.sh"
sleep 99999999
```

The objective is for `foox.sh` to wait on `fooy.sh` for 4 seconds then time out with a non zero exit code on the timeout command.

However, I get that the PID of the `fooy.sh` process in a not a child process of `foox.sh` which makes no sense to me, and thus the question.

Here is standard output:

> foox
>   waiting on 48145
>   fooy.sh
>   /usr/bin/wait: line 4: wait: pid 48145 is not a child of this shell
>   waited on 48145 with result 48145

Comment: Have a look here... https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/427133

Comment: The `wait` must be executed by the process that created the background PID.  When you use `timeout 4 wait ${pid}`, you're running a new process (`timeout`) and it has no child process with PID equal to `${pid}`.  Any workaround is going to be complex.  Note that a process can only wait for its own children to die; it cannot wait for grandchildren to die, nor for siblings, nor for parents.

Comment: Circular cross-site links — the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/427115/15168) question links back to SO and [Wait for a process to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1058047/15168).